# Is $x^T (\sum_{i} e^{\lambda_i} A_i)^{-1} x + \ln \det \sum_{i} e^{\lambda_i} A_i $ a convex function in $\lambda$, where $A_i$ p.d.?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, matrix-calculus, positive-definite

Consider fixed,linearly independent, positive definite matrizes $A_i$ and a fixed, nonzero $x$.

For $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^k$, define $$A(\lambda) = (\sum_{i}^{k} e^{\lambda_i} A_i)^{-1}$$

and $$f(\lambda) = x^T A(\lambda) x + \ln \det A(\lambda)^{-1}$$.

I am trying to find out, whether $f$ is convex. The motivation behind this, is that I have seen this as a way to parameterize a covariance matrix in terms of the sum of some fixed, known matrizes, and was asking myself whether the ensuing optimization problem is convex.

My approach so far: I want to consider the hessian of $f$ and check it for positive-definite-ness.
We have that $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \lambda_i \partial \lambda_j} f(\lambda) = x^T \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \lambda_i \partial \lambda_j} A(\lambda) x + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \lambda_i \partial \lambda_j} \ln \det A(\lambda)^{-1}$$

and thus we want to check whether for all $y$,

$$ \sum_{i,j} y_j \left(x^T \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \lambda_i \partial \lambda_j} A(\lambda)x  + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \lambda_i \partial \lambda_j} \ln \det A(\lambda)^{-1}\right)  y_j > 0$$

I get that

$$ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \lambda_i \partial \lambda_j} A(\lambda) = \\ A(\lambda) \left(e^{\lambda_i} A_i A(\lambda) e^{\lambda_j} A_j + e^{\lambda_j} A_j A(\lambda) e^{\lambda_i} A_i - \delta_{i,j} e^{\lambda_i} A_i \right)A(\lambda) ,$$

and $$  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \lambda_i \partial \lambda_j} \ln \det A(\lambda)^{-1} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda_i}\text{tr}[ A(\lambda) \frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda_j}\ A(\lambda)^{-1}] \\
= \text{tr}[\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda_i} A(\lambda) \frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda_j}\ A(\lambda)^{-1}] +\text{tr}[ A(\lambda) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \lambda_i \partial \lambda_j}\ A(\lambda)^{-1}] = \text{tr}[-A(\lambda) e^{\lambda_i}A_i A(\lambda) e^{\lambda_j} A_j] +  \text{tr}[ A(\lambda)  \delta_{i,j} e^{\lambda_i}A_i]] $$

One can also  summarize this,  using the cyclic property of the trace and symmetry,as
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \lambda_i \partial \lambda_j} f(\lambda) =
\text{tr}[A(\lambda) \left(e^{\lambda_i} A_i A(\lambda) e^{\lambda_j} A_j\right)A(\lambda) (2 xx^T - A(\lambda)^{-1})] + \text{tr}[A(\lambda)\delta_{i,j} e^{\lambda_i}A_i A(\lambda) (A(\lambda)^{-1} - xx^T)] $$

but I do not know hot to proceed now.

Any ideas? Is this even the way to go, or is there a simpler way to see it?

Comment: Have you tried to disprove the statement? Or do you have any reason to believe that the statement should be true?

Comment: I have seen now that it will already fail in one-dimensional examples, so it will not be true in general. The motivation behind that was that I have seen it in statistics, where this was used as a parameterization of a covariance matrix in terms of the sums of individual,fixed positive definite matrizes. And I wondered why it was parameterized like this and not using the inverse, which would easily be convex. However, I also see now that I forgot about the $\ln \det$-term, so I will maybe modify this question..

Answer (score 1):

I ran some simulations and it doesn't seem to be convex. Here is the code (Python):

```
import numpy as np
A1=np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
A2=np.array([[2,-1],[-1,2]])
x=np.ones(2)
def F(lam):
    Ainv=np.exp(lam[0])*A1+np.exp(lam[1])*A2
    return np.dot(x.T,np.dot(np.linalg.inv(Ainv),x))+np.linalg.slogdet(Ainv)[1]

is_convex=True
for _ in range(10000):
    lam0=3*np.random.randn(2)
    lam1=3*np.random.randn(2)
    xx=.5
    below_secant=F(xx*lam0+(1-xx)*lam1)<=xx*F(lam0)+(1-xx)*F(lam1)
    is_convex =is_convex and  below_secant
print(is_convex)
```

Comment: Nice idea, I did not think of this. Do you mind if I leave the question open for an analytical solution?

Comment: @a_student of course, it's your question